# Django 1.10 add media url to static image file

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

After update to Django 1.10 I have a problem with static file images. Now Django add to static file path "media" link... For example before it was "/static/images/avatar.jpeg" now "/**media**/static/images/avatar.jpeg"

Admin [image]

Settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'



STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
        'static',
    )

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Did you add media url in main urls.py?

Comment: Yes. Before update it worked. I think it's linked with new url usage, but I don't have any ideas.
`urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`